# is there any way to implement a machine learning model that can predict most occured sentence in a given dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

is there any way to implement a machine learning model that can predict the topmost occurred sentences in a given dataset?
let's say I have a dataset that contains sentences like this.

```
-> this is a machine learning model.
-> this is a machine learning model.
-> A language model can predict the probability of the next word in the sequence.
-> Build a Deep Neural Network for Sentiment Classification.
-> this is a machine learning model.
-> Build a Deep Neural Network for Sentiment Classification.
```

so the model should predict results like: 
 this is a machine learning model.
 Build a Deep Neural Network for Sentiment Classification.

Comment: I am trying to understand the prediction methodology. Are you just trying to predict for a given corpus of sentences (i.e., predict the most frequent given the number of occurrences, in which case it would be a dictionary using count, which is a naive methodology)? Or are you using the above as, let's say, a training set, then trying to predict what sentence may come next? The question is a bit vague

Comment: It would be a training set that contains the most frequently asked questions by users over a time period. I want to predict the most frequently asked questions with a machine learning model(i.e., predict the most frequent asked question without given the number of occurrences)

Comment: how do you get the most frequently asked question, without counting them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no model required, you can use sentence frequency for it(derive the frequency threshold based on the analysis or give the head 2(or) 3 based on requirement).